# How can exception break through try\catch block?

Tags: c#, exception, behavior

A citation from "The art of unit testing" book:

> In Rhino Mocks, strict mocks are created by calling the StrictMock
>   method. Unexpected method call exceptions will always be thrown,
>   even if your test contains a global try-catch clause, which you’d think
>   would catch such an exception thrown from the isolation framework.

So how exactly can I implement this behaviour in the program of my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way might be to implement an interception framework, such as `Unity.Interception` (others also exists, e.g. from Castle).

Using Unity.Interception you can write an implementation of `ICallHandler`, which has an `Invoke` method where you can trap and re-throw exceptions:

```
public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
{
    var methodReturn = getNext().Invoke(input, getNext);

    // did the method raise an exception?
    if (methodReturn.Exception != null)
    {
        // handle it... re-throw it if necessary...
    }
}
```

Of course delving into the source code of Rhino.Mocks would be the most direct way to do this.  At the very least, use Reflector and browse the dll.

Answer (score 1):

You should never really have this type of scenario in your application as you shouldn't be catching *global* exceptions. You should only catch the type of exceptions you are going to handle, everything else should be allowed to bubble up.